# How to replace values in only some columns in Python without it affecting the same values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numeric, categorical-data

- I have a Pandas data frame with different columns.

  - Some columns are just “yes” or “no” answers that I would need to replace with 1 and 0
  - Some columns are 1s and 2s, where 2 equals no - these 2 need to be replaced by 0
  - Other columns are Numerical categories, for example 1,2,3,4,5 where 1 = lion 2 = dog
  - Other columns are string categories, like: “A lot”, “A little” etc
- The first 2 columns are the target variables

My problem issues:

1. If I just change all 2 to 0 in the data frame, it would end up changing the 2 in the target variable (which in this case act as a score rather than a “No”)
2. Another problem would be that columns with categories as numbers, will have their 2s changed to 0 as well

How can I clean this dataframe so that
2. all columns with either yes or 1 and those with either no or 2 -> become 1 and 0s
3. the two target variables -> stay as scores from 1-5
4. and all categorical variables remain unchanged until I do onehot encoding with them.

These are the steps I took:

1. To change all the “yes” or “no” to 0 and 1
   df.replace(('Yes', 'No'), (1, 0), inplace=True)
2. Now in order to replace all the 2s that act as “No”s with 0s -

   1. without it affecting neither the “2” that act as a score in first two target columns
   2. nor the “2” that act as a category value in columns that have more than 2 unique values, I think I would need to combine the following two lines of code, is that correct? I am trying different ways to combine them but I keep getting errors

df.loc[:, df.nunique() <= 2] or df[df.columns.difference([‘target1 ‘,’target2 '])].replace(2, 0)

Comment: simply use `df[column_name].replace(...)` to work only with selected column

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you showed your code here and a sample of the database. I'm a bit confused. Here is what I gleaned:

First, here is a dummy dataset I created:

[image]

Here is the code that I think solves your two problems. If there is something missing, it's because I didn't quite get the explanation as I said.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'data.csv')
sample = pd.read_csv(filename)

# This solves your first problem. Here we create a new column using numeric values instead of yes/no string values
#with a function
def create_answers_column(sample, colname):
    def is_yes(a):
        if a == 'yes':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    return sample[colname].apply(is_yes)
sample['Answers Numeric'] = create_answers_column(sample, 'Answers')


#This solves your second problem
#Using replace()
sample['Numbers'] = sample.Numbers.replace({2:0})

print(sample)
```

And here's the output:

```
Answers  Numbers  Animals Quantifiers  Answers Numeric
0     yes        1        1       a lot                1
1     yes        0        2      little                1
2      no        0        3        many                0
3     yes        1        4        some                1
4      no        1        5     several                0
```